# Selenium Web driver ( driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '')) IS NOT WORKING Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/aamer-jamal-793441
This is the URL and here i am trying to access Full Name "Aamer Jamal". with the help of selenium web driver. But I dont know why it gives

```
NoSuchElementException
```

### `the code is written below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium_firefox import Firefox
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#Reach to the Landing page
driver.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/aamer-jamal-793441')
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(25)
not_now = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'wzrk-cancel')
not_now.click()

fullname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/section/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/h5')
print(fullname.text)`
```

Error :

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/section/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span
```

Comment: I dont know why this error occurs I give enough time (25 sec) to load the page but still it gives this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits, not a long hardcoded pauses. You also have to learn how to create correct locators. Long absolute XPaths and CSS Selectors are extremely breakable. The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/aamer-jamal-793441"

driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'wzrk-cancel')))
fullname = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ds-text-title-l'))).text
print(fullname)
```

The output is:

```
Aamer Jamal
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it worked perfectly fine for me. Please can you explain a little bit how can i learn  to create correct locators or what do you mean by correct locators. What is the correct way to locate any element. Please guide me about this. and also please refer me, from where can i learn this concept. THanks again.